# Show that $\frac{n}{2}<\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}<n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Show that

> $$\frac{n}{2}<\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}<n$$

Hence show that

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\rightarrow\infty\ as\ n\rightarrow\infty$$.
>
> Group the terms thus: $$\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+...)$$

I am novice to the limit of sequence chapter and finding it tough to solve.

Please explain me the concept involved with the question and the technique to solve such problems. Reference study notes will be a great help.
[image]

Source : Barnard and Child Higher Algebra Exercise XXIV

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Perhaps the sum goes to $2^n$ instead of $2n$ ?

Comment: No,it goes to 2n.

Comment: try using industion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a typo in the book.

The hint points to the [classical proof of the divergence of the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test), which ends with
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \,\frac{1}{k} \;\geq\; 1 + \frac{n}{2}$$
and this is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=2}^{2^n} \,\frac{1}{k} \;\geq\; \frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: @ihf. yes I missed that. Anyways can you please just explain what basically it imply grouping the terms.

Comment: @ihf but the series went till 2n and then it was groupped and the later is performed. But grouping the terms gives an infinite series.